# В genymotion работают deprecated классы, а на устройстве нет

Tags: android, httpclient, genymotion

Странная ситуация:
я компилю приложение в *Андроид Студии*, запускаю в genymotion эмулятор - *Nexus 5 Android 5.1.0* и запускаю на нем приложение - все ок работает.

Сбрасываю на устройство и там

> Application has been stoped

. Падает на deprecated класах - HttpClient, HttpGet - устаревший с версии *Андроида Lollipop*.

Вопрос: почему так выходит, что на эмуляторе они работают, а не устройстве(*Android Lollipop*) нет ?

Как сделать так, чтобы на эмуляторе приложение тоже падало так же как и на девайсе?

Comment: В официальном эмуляторе тоже не падает? В genymotion установлен cyanogemod, возможно, связано. На устройствах с android 5.0/5.1  работают все deprecated классы, в том числе и HttpClient (иначе бы перестала работать четверть приложений на маркете). Проблема где-то в другом месте, приложите трейс

Comment: @lsillarionov, я уже решил эту проблему использованием HttpURLConnection.. но вопрос терзает вопрос почему так ? Попробую на офф. эмуляторе, спасибо Вам за идею)